# How to fix 'PROXIES is empty' error for scrapy spider

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, scrapy

I am trying to run a scrapy spider through the use of a proxy and am getting errors whenever I run the code.

This is for Mac OSX, python 3.7, scrapy 1.5.1.
I have tried playing around with the settings and middlewares but to no effect.

```
class superSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    def start_requests(self):
        print('request')
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('parse')
```

The errors I get are:

```
2019-02-15 08:32:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started 
(bot: superScraper)
2019-02-15 08:32:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 
4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, 
Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 
03:13:28) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 
1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 2.4.2, Platform Darwin-17.7.0- 
x86_64-i386-64bit
2019-02-15 08:32:27 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: 
{'BOT_NAME': 'superScraper', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 25, 
'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'superScraper.spiders', 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES':         
 [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408], 'RETRY_TIMES': 10,     
'SPIDER_MODULES': ['superScraper.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 
'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; 
+http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)'}
2019-02-15 08:32:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2019-02-15 08:32:27 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File
```

`"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 171, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 175, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 36, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py", line 99, in from_crawler
    return cls(crawler.settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py", line 74, in __init__
    raise KeyError('PROXIES is empty')
builtins.KeyError: 'PROXIES is empty'`

These websites are from the documentation for scrapy and it works without using a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having a similar problem, this was an issue with my actual scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy code

Using the code here made it work:
https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies

Go into the scrapy_proxies folder and replace the RandomProxy.py code with the one found on github

Mine was found here:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py